# How to change tooltip color on open using jQuery UI Tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm trying to achieve the following, can't figure out how though. I have several tooltips on a page, but I want each one to look different (depending on severity for instance). Here is what I have so far:

```
<div id="container">
<a href="#" title="Tooltip 1" data-severity="warning">Tooltip 1 (Warning)</a>
<a href="#" title="Tooltip 2" data-severity="danger">Tooltip 2 (Danger)</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// init tooltip
ArrowToolTip.init('container');
</script>

/*JAVASCRIPT*/
var ArrowToolTip = {
init: function (parentId) {
    jQuery('#' + parentId).tooltip(
    {
        content: function () {
            var element = jQuery(this);
            return element.attr('title');
        },
        create: function () {
            var element = jQuery(this);

            var severity = element.data('severity');

            if (!severity) {
                severity = 'default';
            }

            element.tooltip('option', 'tooltipClass', severity);
        },
        open: function(event, ui) {
            var element = jQuery(this);
            var severity = element.data('severity');
            ui.tooltip({
                tooltipClass: severity 
            });
            //ui.tooltip.tooltipClass(severity);
            console.log(event);
            console.log(ui);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Whatever I have in the create: works, but it's only called on page load, so that doesn't do me any good. So now I'm trying to move this to the `open:` event. But that doesn't seem to work at all. The `jQuery(this)` doesn't return the hovered element, it returns the container. How can I get the correct element to select the data attribute? And how can I then change the CSS class? Does anyone know how this could be achieved?

Comment: Try `var element = ui.tooltip;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't get your logic very well, but here's how I achieve different classes depending on `data-severity`. Instead of applying `.tooltip()` to all elements, iterate through them and set the `tooltipClass` as `$(this).data('severity')`. The content function allows to add a class too.

```js
$('a.tips').each(function () {
    var severity = $(this).data('severity');
    $(this).tooltip({
        content: function () {
            return '<em>' + $(this).attr('title') + '</em>';
        },
        tooltipClass: severity,
        show: "slideDown",
        open: function (event, ui) {
            ui.tooltip.hover(function () {
                $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.ui-tooltip {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font: bold 14px"Helvetica Neue", Sans-Serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px black;
}
.ui-tooltip.warning {
    color: #E3E8F7;
    background: #D94AA4;
}
.ui-tooltip.danger {
    color: #212942;
    background: #CABA75;
}
a.tips { float:left; margin: 0 10px; text-decoration:none; font: Sans-Serif; }
body { background-color:#eee; padding: 30px; }
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/css/jquery.ui.tooltip.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
<a href="#" title="Tooltip 1" class="tips" data-severity="warning">(Warning)</a>
<a href="#" title="Tooltip 2" class="tips" data-severity="danger">(Danger)</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @5earch, this seems the correct way.. and if your severity is same at first and then it is changing dynamically, then u may have to re-bind the tooltip by calling the same code on whenever the severity changes.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

i am not clear about your quection.
But i hope this will help you sometimes....

I am using tooltipClass name as "tooltipclass" in my jquery.

```
$(document).tooltip({effect: "blind", duration: 1000, tooltipClass: 'tooltipclass'});
```

And using that class name you can give any styling to the tool tip.

```
.tooltipclass{
    font-size: 12px;
    border:1px solid #e74c3c;
}
```

so try using different tooltipClass names.........

Comment: Thanks for you answer. That's not quite what I had in mind though. I want to change the color onHover so its different for every tooltip and not just set it initially so it's for all the same.